# Which would be more efficient for JavaScript to process?

Tags: javascript

I am working with large arrays and am wondering which method of array gathering would be most efficient.

```
var stk = 0;
var eqt = document.getElementById("text1").value;
var val = document.getElementById("value1").value;
while (stk < 3340) {
    var opneqt = eqt.replace(new RegExp("opn", "g"), open[stk]);
    var higeqt = opneqt.replace(new RegExp("hig", "g"), high[stk]);
    var loweqt = higeqt.replace(new RegExp("low", "g"), low[stk]);
    var cloeqt = loweqt.replace(new RegExp("clo", "g"), close[stk]);
    var voleqt = cloeqt.replace(new RegExp("vol", "g"), volume[stk]);
    var feqt = eval(voleqt);
    var opnval = val.replace(new RegExp("opn", "g"), open[stk]);
    var higval = opnval.replace(new RegExp("hig", "g"), high[stk]);
    var lowval = higval.replace(new RegExp("low", "g"), low[stk]);
    var cloval = lowval.replace(new RegExp("clo", "g"), close[stk]);
    var volval = cloval.replace(new RegExp("vol", "g"), volume[stk]);
    var fval = eval(volval);

    stk++;
}
```

I have a textarea where people will write equations using variables such as (opn, hig, low, clo, and vol). I then process this data by replacing all of the variables with their matching array value (see code above). This loop is repeated 3340 times. The thing is the textarea might only contain one or two of these variables so I was wondering if doing an if includes(variable) before each substitution would be faster.

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: No, but *one regex* would be faster than *multiple regex*

Comment: Create `low`, `hig` etc variables with the corresponding current array values then they will be in scope of the eval, E.g. `eval("hig + low")` would work as is?

Comment: @Alex K., That would be the same as what I have because each time you enter the loop you have to redefine the variable to the new array value. What i'm asking, I guess, is if the string doesn't contain the variable does regex still go and gather the array value, making it inefficient.

Comment: I meant that `var opn = open[stk];` etc removes the need for a RegEx which removes the conundrum about determining if the RegEx will have an effect.